# First SQL result dropped from results

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql

It doesn't matter what the first document is called, it is always excluded from the list with this code. I can run the same select statement against the DB and the correct results show.  I think I have just looked at the code too much to see the issue.

```
SqlConnection objConn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DBName"].ToString());

            objConn.Open();

            string sTSQL =
                        "SELECT [filename]      " +
                        "FROM [DB].[dbo].[secure_files] ";

            SqlCommand objCmd = new SqlCommand(sTSQL, objConn);
            objCmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

            SqlDataReader dr = objCmd.ExecuteReader();
            dr.Read();

            html += "<ul>";

            while (dr.Read())
            {
                html += "<li><a href=\"/secure/secureDownload.aspx?query=" + dr[0].ToString() + "\">" + dr[0].ToString() + "</a></li>";
            }
            html += "</ul>";

            objConn.Close();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this is because you call `dr.Read();` twice. Just remove the first one.

Comment: Yeah. Sometimes this happens. :)

Answer (score 0):

You're reading once but not saving what you read, then you read again at the start of your loop.

Remove your first `dr.Read()` line. You just want to be reading in the loop.

Answer (score 0):

```
dr.Read();

html += "<ul>";

while (dr.Read())
```

Your first dr.Read() skips over the first record.

Answer (score 0):

Get rid of the first dr.Read() outside of the while loop. Its is skipping over the first record.